# How does numpy.ravel_multi_index work?

Tags: python, numpy

Can someone please explain to me what this function does ? I don't understand the documentation and can not see a clear mapping between input to output as given in the examples of the document.

[Link](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel_multi_index.html)

Comment: For the 1st example: `np.arange(7*6).reshape(7,6)[[3,6,6],[4,5,1]]` produces `array([22, 41, 37])`, which is also `(3*6+4, 6*6+5, 6*6+1)`.